# Conjunctions after "Somewhere"

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

I was writing a letter when I realized that I had no idea what conjunction to put after ***somewhere***:

> I found somewhere ____ I fit in.

Which of these make sense?

- Where (seems redundant)
- That (seems ok)
- Eliminating the *somewhere* and replacing it with *someplace* and using 'where' (sounds unnatural)
- Eliminating the *somewhere* and replacing it with *a place* and using 'where' (sounds ok)
- Eliminating the *somewhere* and replacing it with *a place* and using 'that' (sounds ok)

Which of these sounds the most normal? Is it something else? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be talking about *relative pronouns*, not *conjunctions*. Conjunctions include the FANBOYS (for, and, not, but, or, yet, since). Relative pronouns include *that*, *which*, *when*, *where*). See [this page](http://www.perfectyourenglish.com/grammar/conjunctions-relative-pronouns.htm) to see how they differ and how they can act similarly. Or Google "relative pronouns and conjunctions".

Answer (score 2):

I'd say your intuition and ear are right on. Choose any of those that sound OK to you; they are all grammatically correct and commonly used.

You are right that "somewhere where" is redundant. Actually, you could use "somewhere I fit in" without any other pronoun.